# Finding intervals of latitude/longitude of cities throughout the world at 0.01° precision

Tags: coordinate-system, data, coordinates, latitude-longitude, area

Geographical coordinates determine a specific point on a map.

I am searching for the coordinates interval (thus to frame the area) of different large cities by latitude/longitude at a 0.01°x0.01° precision.

Would you have any resources that could help me?

Comment: Get the administrative boundaries/areas and reproject them in a geographic crs?

Comment: I have to find the areas of about 100 cities all around the world (some of them located in less developed countries) in a short amount of time. I figured there might be a faster way and better way to get the coordinates' interval.

Comment: Are you aware that a square degree decreases in area when you move away from the equator?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry, I might have not written very well my question, I just edited it. I am searching, for each city I am interested in (mainly big cities in Asia), the square of coordinates defining their area. I thought there might be an official source or some lists of cities with the square of geographical coordinates covering their area.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: And the technical term you are looking for is called "bounding box"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440102/getting-bounding-box-of-city) and the following website can be used to find a bounding box of any city in the world : https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php